# Find the probability that only one event happens

Tags: probability

$P(A) = 0.35$, $P(B) = 0.72$ Probability that at least one of these two events happen = $0.90$. What is the probability of only one of these events happen?

So far, I tried doing $P(A \cap B^c) + P(A^c \cap B)$ And also tried $1 - P(A \cap B) - P(A^c \cap B^c)$ but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$$
Then, since $(A\cap B)\subset (A\cup B)$, we have
$$P((A\cup B)\text{ \ }(A\cap B))$$$$=P(A\cup B)-P(A\cap B)$$$$=2P(A\cup B)-P(A)-P(B)$$
$$=2\cdot0.90-0.35-0.72=0.73$$

Answer (score 1):

You have $P(A), P(B), P(A\cup B)$ and should know that $\mathsf P(A\cup B)=\mathsf P(A)+\mathsf P(B)-\mathsf P(A\cap B)$ from the Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion.

Now find $\mathsf P((A\cup B)\smallsetminus(A\cap B))$, the probability for one or the other happening but not both.

Comment: So $P(A \cap B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cup B)$ and then divide $P(A \cap B)$ by $P(A \cup B)$?

Comment: No. Why would you *divide* to obtain the probability of a set difference?

Comment: I dont know, haha. What does the \ mean in your answer

Comment: set difference.  $X\smallsetminus Y = X\cap  Y^\complement$

Answer (score 0):

hint...First use $p(A\cup B)=p(A)+p(B)-p(A\cap B)$ to get $p(A\cap B)$

Then you need $p(A\cup B)-p(A\cap B)$